# Does someone knows why MSYS2 installer pops-up every time i open vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, msys2

Do you know why the MSYS2 installer keeps popping up every time I open VS Code? I can't seem to close it as it reappears persistently. Please help me, as I am new to this. I've attempted to close it through the task manager, but it reappears every time. Someone mentioned a possible connection with PowerShell, but I'm not certain.

Comment: This is odd. I have used msys2 for a couple of years and have never seen that behavior with VSCode. Does it happen after a reboot.

Comment: yeah i know but it is the first time that i open it

Comment: Show your `settings.json`.